# Does redisearch support nested query?

Tags: python, redis, redisearch

We have nested data in Elasticsearch and would like to move from Elasticsearch to Redis.

Does RediSearch support nested queries?

Answer (score 0):

**Redisearch can not query nested json doc.**

Redisearch can not be used as a database. It is designed to do in-memory full text search service.

You can learn more about [the search API](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Commands/#ftsearch) form their document.